# Modify main dashboard in odoo

Tags: javascript, xml, odoo-12

I have created one XML file and a JS file,
I have removed odoo's promotion from dashboard,
it works fine but if i am activating developer mode it just disappear whole settings menu.
here is my code.
XML file:

```
<template>
    <t t-extend="UserMenu">
        <t t-jquery="div.dropdown-menu.dropdown-menu-right"
           t-operation="replace">
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"/>
                <a role="menuitem" href="#" data-menu="Shortcuts"
                   class="dropdown-item">Shortcuts</a>
                <a role="menuitem" href="#" data-menu="settings"
                   class="dropdown-item">Preferences</a>
                <a role="menuitem" href="#" data-menu="logout"
                   class="dropdown-item">Log out</a>
            </div>
        </t>
    </t>

<t t-extend="DashboardShare">
    <t t-jquery="div.o_web_settings_dashboard_share" t-operation="replace">
        <div class="text-center o_web_settings_dashboard_share">
            <i class="fa fa-share-alt fa-4x text-muted"/>
            <div class="o_web_settings_dashboard_header">Share the Love</div>
            <div>
                <small class="text-muted text-center o_web_settings_dashboard_compact_subtitle">
                    Help us spread the word: Share with your friends!

                </small>
            </div>
            <div class="row mt16">
            </div>
            <br/>
            <t t-set="server_version" t-value="widget.data.server_version"/>
            <t t-set="debug" t-value="widget.data.debug"/>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <a t-if="debug != true" class="oe_activate_debug_mode pull-right" href="?debug=assets" >Activate the developer mode</a>
                    <br t-if="debug != true"/>
                    <a t-if="debug != 'assets'" class="oe_activate_debug_mode pull-right" href="?debug=assets" >Activate the developer mode (with assets)</a>
                    <br t-if="debug != 'assets'"/>
                    <a t-if="debug != false" class="oe_activate_debug_mode pull-right" href="/web" >Deactivate the developer mode</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </t>
</t>
</template>
```

JS file:

```
odoo.define('backend_branding_app.dashboard', function (require) {
"use strict";

    var dashboard = require('web_settings_dashboard');
    dashboard.Dashboard.include({
        start: function(){
            this.all_dashboards  = _.without(this.all_dashboards, 'planner', 'apps');
            this.$('.o_web_settings_dashboard_apps').parent().remove();
            this.$('.o_web_settings_dashboard_planner').parent().remove();
            return this._super();
        },
    });
});
```

where is I'm making mistake?

Comment: What is odoo's promotion?

Comment: that promotion banner.